# Inserting XLSX data inside a database

Tags: java, excel, sqlite, netbeans, apache-poi

I've been creating a small app that will be used with a barcode scanner (or a number written by hand in a jtextfield) that reads an excel .xlsx file and writes the relevant values in an sqlite file.

The data is "fixed" (it's always going to be the first 7 columns and formatted as text in excel) but the row number isn't.

I've got the program to work, but it suddenly stopped working this week (I've tried reverting to earlier commits as well and no luck) and I'm struggling to understand what I am doing wrong with it.

```
class ImportWorker extends SwingWorker<Integer , Integer>{
    JProgressBar jpb;
    int max;
    Sheet sheet;
    File file;

    //Passo i valori di questa classe come riferimenti di oggetti presenti nell'EDB, cosi' posso aggiornare i valori li'
    public ImportWorker(JProgressBar jpb, int max, Sheet sheet, File file){
        this.jpb = jpb;
        this.max = max;
        this.sheet = sheet;
        this.file = file;
    }

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground() throws Exception {
            //Svolgo il mio Import dentro un Thread separato dall'EDB cosi' il programma non si blocca

            Row row;
            String sql = "jdbc:sqlite:"+dbPath;
            try{
                conn = DriverManager.getConnection(sql);
                String sql2 = "DELETE FROM libri";
                Statement = conn.prepareStatement(sql2);
                Statement.execute();
                Statement.close();


                for (int i = 0; i <= sheet.getLastRowNum(); i++) {
                    //attivo progress bar con il ciclo per visualizzare lo stato di caricamento del file
                   int pbpercentage = (100 * i)/(max);


                    //conversione dei valore ed inserimento dentro il database
                    row = sheet.getRow(i);

                    row.getCell(0).setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
                    String Nome = row.getCell(0).getStringCellValue();

                    row.getCell(1).setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
                    String Autore = row.getCell(1).getStringCellValue();

                    row.getCell(2).setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
                    String Casa = row.getCell(2).getStringCellValue();

                    row.getCell(3).setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
                    String Codice = row.getCell(3).getStringCellValue();

                    row.getCell(4).setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
                    String Prezzo = row.getCell(4).getStringCellValue();

                    row.getCell(5).setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
                    String Anno = row.getCell(5).getStringCellValue();

                    row.getCell(6).setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
                    String Indice = row.getCell(6).getStringCellValue();



                    String sql1 = "INSERT INTO libri (Nome, Autore, Casa, Codice, Prezzo, Anno, Indice) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
                    Statement = conn.prepareStatement(sql1);
                    Statement.setString(1, Nome);
                    Statement.setString(2, Autore);
                    Statement.setString(3, Casa);
                    Statement.setString(4, Codice);
                    Statement.setString(5, Prezzo);
                    Statement.setString(6, Anno);
                    Statement.setString(7, Indice);
                    Statement.execute();
                    Statement.close();

                    publish(pbpercentage);
                }
                conn.close();

            }catch(SQLException e){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "leggi() SwingWorker", "Errore", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        return null;

    }

    @Override
    protected void process(List<Integer> chunks) {
        //Aggiornamento della percentuale della progress bar
        int i = chunks.get(chunks.size()-1);
        jpb.setValue(i);
    }

    @Override
    protected void done() {
        //Imposto il messaggio dei due Jlabel
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

        eventi.setText(dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()));
        eventi2.setText("FILE "+ file.getName() +" IMPORTATO");

        //Nascondo la barra
        jpb.setVisible(false);
        setCursor(null);
    }
}
```

This is the relevant portion of the code I am using, it uses a swingworker so that I can update a progressbar and check the status of the operation, the problem is that in the program when I select the file, the for loop starts and ends immediately printing out the label "File" FILE_NAME "importato" after a couple of seconds (it's supposed to do that when finishing with the whole sheet).

I've tried adding System.out.println to various stages of the process and it seems that it correctly enters inside the for loop but just drops out without even reaching the end of the first loop.

Please excuse the comments in an other language I'm happy to translate whatever you don't understand!

P.S. the database table is called "libri" and it has 8 columns (the first one is a PK called Id)

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: EDIT: After experimenting more I noticed that it was kicking out of the for loop only at certain rows, in short the problem resided in the fact that POI would consider blank cells as NULL and throw a NullPointerException (you can also catch this with a Throwable since it's thrown at runtime), the solution was to introduce if cluases before grabbing the cell values and setting the Strings that I have to insert inside the database as null from the beginning.